# Laravel 4 stream mp3 from s3 without CNAME buckets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, amazon-s3, laravel-routing

According to other answers, the best way is to create a CNAME bucket / record and stream that way.  However, I am unable to do this due to copyright concerns and I must stream it through my app (in order to log user plays, among many other things).

I have mp3's on S3 in my bucket `my-bucket`.  The mp3's are publicly accessible at `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket`.

I have this code as my router:

```
Router.php
Route::get("/music/{id}.mp3", "Controller\Music@play");

Music.php
namespace Controller;

class Music extends \Controller\Base
{
    public function play($id)
    {
        $return = file_get_contents("https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/$id");

        if( !$return )
            return "false";

        $response = Response::make($return, 200)->header('Content-Type', "audio/mpeg");
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Now, on my ssl-secured server, the actual audio file will display but it will not actually play or stream.  Any idea on how to achieve this?

edit: Also, I do realize I would be paying double the bandwidth costs (s3 to servers, servers to world) and that is completely fine.

Comment: Why are you returning a `400` http status code? That means `Bad Request`.

Comment: Very good question... I'm not quite sure.  However, even after changing to 200, it still won't stream

Comment: Try setting also the content length header for your response (I'm guessing that might be needed by any player for preloading). So something like `$response->header('Content-Length', strlen($return));`.